# How do I exclude records with mysql if?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that loops through a table of events.  We're only interested in the first tests taken that day if that first test passed. So, for example, if we have:

```
s/n     test_result first test taken and passed
DX123   Terminated  2016-06-16 09:33:38
DX124   Passed      2016-06-16 10:12:01
DX125   Failed      2016-06-16 08:27:48
DX126   Passed      2016-06-16 08:28:16
DX127   Passed      2016-06-16 08:25:02
```

Then what we want is only those first tests that passed.  If DX125 went on to pass half an hour later then we don't want DX125 in the dataset.

So the table above would return:

```
s/n     test_result first test taken and passed
DX124   Passed      2016-06-16 10:12:01
DX126   Passed      2016-06-16 08:28:16
DX127   Passed      2016-06-16 08:25:02
```

I've tried using:

```
select serial_number, test_name, 
    IF(test_result = 'passed', min(START_DATE_TIME), null) as 'first test taken and passed' 

from 
    test_results 
 where
     (test_time > '2016-06-16 00:00:00' AND test_time < '2016-06-16 23:59:59')

group by serial_number, test_name 
order by serial_number asc;
```

That returns the failed tests as nulls, I'd rather they weren't there at all.  This would be achieved elegantly by setting the `if` statement to return nothing if false.  Can it be done?

Thanks.

Comment: The column names in your input data and query do not agree, and also there is no sample output.  Can you clarify your question by showing us what output you want?

Comment: Did you just want row `DX127   Passed      2016-06-16 08:25:02`?

Comment: Test this select serial_number, test_name, min(START_DATE_TIME) as 'first test taken and passed' 
    
    from 
        test_results 
     where
         date(test_time)  = '2016-06-16' and test_result = 'passed'
    
    group by serial_number, test_name 
    order by serial_number asc;

Comment: @Rakesh no, that returns the first test passed.  I want to return the first test taken that day *if* it passed.

Comment: @10086 no, I want all records that passed the first test they took.  So, get the first test of the day on each serial number.  Add to the dataset if it was passed, discard it if is wasn't.  I'll edit the question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen done.

Comment: @gedq I gave you an answer below.  I think your original query was very close.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Having()` clause to exclude rows after grouping:

```
SELECT serial_number,
       test_name,
       IF(status = "Passed",CONVERT(MIN(test_time), CHAR),'not passed') AS 'first_test_taken_and_passed'
FROM 
    test_results 
WHERE
    test_time > '2016-06-16 00:00:00'
    AND test_time <= '2016-06-16 23:59:59'
GROUP BY serial_number, test_name 
HAVING first_test_taken_and_passed <> "not passed"
ORDER BY serial_number ASC
```

**Edit**: Updated answer according to first comment. Included `Having()` clause

Comment: Nope, that is returning the first test that passed.  I need the first test taken if it passed.

Comment: Now I understood. I edited the answer to fit your needs. You need a `Having()` clause.

Comment: @Djeramon I have no idea what he is asking, but I just updated my query again.  Maybe one of us will get it.

Comment: "the first test if it passed, not the first test that passed".  I'll update my question.

Answer (score 1):

This query will give the serial number, test name, and earliest time of test taking, for those groups which do not have any failures in them.  The `HAVING` clause filters away groups which had one or more failures.

```
SELECT serial_number,
       test_name,
       MIN(test_time) AS 'first test taken and passed'
FROM 
    test_results 
WHERE
    test_time > '2016-06-16 00:00:00' AND test_time < '2016-06-16 23:59:59'
GROUP BY serial_number, test_name 
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN test_result != 'passed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
ORDER BY serial_number ASC
```